# Replace String in Manifest in build time doesn't work on Gradle 2.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED` error.
Problem is that String that should be replaced in Android Manifest in build time is not. All started after I updated Gradle version 2.1
Before update to Gradle 2.1 (from 2.0) my code was working. Now I am getting following error log:

```
> Failed parse during installPackageLI
android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: /data/app/vmdl264927358.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #16): Bad class name PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE in package my.package.xyz
at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseBaseApk(PackageParser.java:892)
at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseClusterPackage(PackageParser.java:790)
at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:754)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:12252)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-wrap25(PackageManagerService.java)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$9.run(PackageManagerService.java:10170)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Code that I am using to raplace PACKAGE_NAME is:

```
applicationVariants.all {variant ->
    def flavor = variant.productFlavors.get(0)
    def buildType = variant.buildType
    variant.outputs[0].processManifest.doLast {
        replaceInManifest(variant,
                          'PACKAGE_NAME',
                          [flavor.applicationId, buildType.applicationIdSuffix].findAll().join())
    }
}

def replaceInManifest ( variant, fromString, toString ) {
    def flavor = variant.productFlavors.get(0)
    def buildtype = variant.buildType
    def manifestFile = "$buildDir/intermediates/manifests/full/${flavor.name}/${buildtype.name}/AndroidManifest.xml"
    def updatedContent = new File(manifestFile).getText('UTF-8').replaceAll(fromString, toString)
    new File(manifestFile).write(updatedContent, 'UTF-8')
}
```

After the build I checked AndroidManifest.xml file in folder /intermediates/manifests/full/${flavor.name}/${buildtype.name}/AndroidManifest.xml and everything was replaced. It seems that order of execution some parts of code in Gradle file and packaging in .apk were changed.
Do you know what I have to do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was strangest problem ever. Problem was that I had these lines by accident in my gradle script:

```
compile 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick:2.3.6'
provided 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick-processor:2.3.6'
compile 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'
```

But app was build without error and than failed on install apk.

Answer (score 0):

What's your package name? I had this once and changing the package name to small cases fixed my problem

Comment: Package name is in small cases, so that is not a problem.

Comment: Problem is not in AndroidManifest, problem is that Gradle script doesn't replace PACKAGE_NAME in line
 `<permission android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />` in Manifest.